# how to pass htmlunit page as a modelandview (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, testing, htmlunit

I wanted to make a proxy site. 
When user request for a URL. on server side I wanted to request the url and make a object containing the page details (html source, request response etc.)

I found that **htmlunit** can fit for my requirements.
I wanted to pass the response from htmlunit's object to users browser.
(As ModelAndView (Spring) if possible. ) 
How can it be achieved?

```
@Test
public void getElements() throws Exception {
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");
//I wanted to pass the "HtmlPage" to user's browser.
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to content of `http://som_url` to be returned by your controller?

Comment: yup. "new ModelAndView("redirect:"+fwdUrl);" or new ModelAndView("forward:"+fwdUrl);" wont help me.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Spring works. A `ModelAndView` object is a holder for a `View` name and a `Model`. The `View` name is used in conjunction with a `ViewResolver` to render a response. The `Model` serves to hold attributes that might be needed during the rendering process.

If you want to return the content of a separate HTTP request/response, you'll need to execute the HTTP request, get the response body and stream it to the HTTP response. Follow these steps

1. HTTP request to your application
2. Your handler method is invoked
3. You use an HTTP client to send a new HTTP request to some URL
4. You get the HTTP response from that URL
5. You stream that response to your HTTP response.

Comment: I am clear about step 1,2,4and 5 . but I am doubtful about using htmlunit to send a request and stream the response from it. I know spring . I am new to "htmlunit"

Comment: @VishnudevK Take a look at the javadoc. You have [`getWebResponse()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/SgmlPage.html#getWebResponse()) and then [`getContentAsStream()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebResponse.html#getContentAsStream())